# is Synapse Analytics SQL cost effective to store deleted record in dataverse?

Tags: powerapps, azure-synapse, azure-analysis-services, dataverse

I'm newbie to use azure services. I'm using power apps portal for my personal business case were it stores all the business data into dataverse which now holds huge amount of stale data which is not needed. So i need to archive those data. doing some research i got to know about synapse analytics link in power apps which will help us to store the dataverse data into azure synapse sql pool. im pretty confused here. if i can transform only my deleting records into that azure synapse sql pool is possible? or even if i replicate all my dataverse table into azure synapse analytics sql pool will cost more than what it stored at dataverse? basically what im asking is storing data in dataverse is costly or azure synapse sql pool is costly? or suggest me any ways do help me to archive my stale data in dataverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is kind of subjective but i will try to answer to the best of my knowledge

1. if i can transform only my deleting records into that azure synapse sql pool is possible?

Yes this is possible you can build query to extract only data matching your criteria.

2. even if i replicate all my dataverse table into azure synapse analytics sql pool will cost more than what it stored at dataverse?

you can extract everything in your synapse sql pool and then add transformation to delete unwanted data.

3. basically what im asking is storing data in dataverse is costly or azure synapse sql pool is costly?

It is not free i.e it has it's own licensing and is not included in any dataverser or dynamics license.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/synapse-analytics/